# How do I let bash correctly parse filenames with spaces?

Tags: bash

Say I have a executable `myProgram`, who takes a filename as one of the arguments, and output a lot of stuff to `stdout`. Now I want to write a `bash` script to invoke `myProgram` and pipe the output to `less`. Normally I would create a bash script `myCommand`:

```
#!/bin/bash
myProgram $* | less
```

But somehow bash will split any file name with spaces into multiple arguments. For example, it converts

```
myCommand some\ file -m 5
```

into

```
myProgram some file -m 5 | less
```

which of course causes error. Is there a way to resolve this problem? I tried adding `"` around `$*` but then realized that it won't help because it will cause the entire argument list becoming a single argument, which is not what I want.

Comment: Replace `$*` with `"$@"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle whitespaces in arguments to a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564450/handle-whitespaces-in-arguments-to-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `$*` with `"$@"`

`myProgram "$@" | less`